# How to programmatically assign the date to a datetimepicker from a database in c#

Tags: c#

i hav a datetimepicker control whose format i have set to custom as dd/mm/yyyy (with no time). i store this date in a database as varchar and not as datetime because it was giving some sort of error regarding invalid datetime format. i then use a datagrid to display the records from the database. the thing is i need to retrive the date from the datagrid (when the user selects the particular date cell in datagrid)  and want to display it back on the datetimepicker control (so that the user can edit it). i am using the following code to do so:
dtDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dgDetails.SelectedCells[1].FormattedValue);

the error i am getting is "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".
where the dtDate is datetimepicker control, dgDetails is the datagrid and SelectedCells[1] is the cell containing the date.

Comment: You should change your column type back to `datetime` and handle the error you were getting then.

Comment: Storing dates as string in a dbase column must be one the top 3 giant mistakes you can make.  Date formats are *very* culture sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have reacted to the error by changing the type in your database inappropriately - if you're trying to store dates, you should use the closest available type in the database.

The problem was almost certainly that you were querying/updating/inserting by putting the value directly in the SQL instead of using a parameterized query - the right solution is to use a parameterized query.

You've done the same thing with the data grid, by the sounds of it. Why bother parsing something when you can get at the value without going via a string representation? Try:

```
dtDate.Value = (DateTime) dgDetails.SelectedCells[1].Value;
```

Note that it almost certainly wasn't the *assignment* that was failing - it was the call to `Convert.ToDateTime`. (The stack trace should have shown you this.)

Comment: after trying as you suggested, the error "Specified cast is not valid" is coming.

Comment: hey, changed the type of the column in database from varchar to datetime and am now reading the date as dtDate.Value.Date (previously i used to do dtDate.Text which was causing some error) and now it seems to be working. however, it now stores the date as mm/dd/yyyy as opposed to dd/mm/yyyy which i want.

Comment: @Pratik: The database almost certainly isn't "storing" the date in a text format at all, any more than storing "10" stores the digits 1 and 0. It's storing it as an internal representation of a date. If you want those results in a particular format, you should format it appropriate *at that point*... but *store* it in the most appropriate data type.

Comment: actually, while displaying on the datetimepicker it displays as dd/mm/yyyy (which i want). the problem is with datagrid where it displays as mm/dd/yyyy. can u plz suggest how i can manipulate it so that on datagrid also it displays dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set date format for Date column from designer or set below property as required

```
Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format
```